# What are the advantages of using the same interface for different data structures?

Tags: java, interface

What are the advantages of having data structures with the same interface?
Why don't we just give each of one their own interface?

Aren't they are there just to make sure that the functions the interface are implemented in the inheriting class?

Comment: For example we have an interface for items that have to be processed in some order. We can implement this using a stack, queue, circular array etc.

Comment: See [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @scy17 based on what you said, having a single interface to create different data structures as you pointed out basically makes life easier for me because I don't have to go looking up what specific interface I have to use to create a particular structure, so that speaks for easy reuse.

Comment: Thanks! So the advantages are reuse and abstraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the advantages of having several data structures with the same interface?

So that you can treat them the same without having to know which data structure you are dealing with.

> Why don't we just give each of one their own interface?

Because it would be annoying to be forced to deal with all of them separately. If I call some third-party method that returns me a sequence of results, I don't care whether that sequence of results is implemented as a singly-linked list, an array list, a doubly-linked list, a stack, a cons list, a queue, a Patricia Trie, a HAMT, a Bagwell Trie, or some data structure that hasn't even been invented yet.

All I care about is that I can iterate over it.

In other words, the advantages of using the same interface for different data structures are simply the advantages using interfaces *in general*, which is *abstraction*, which in turn as one of the two *fundamental goals* in software design (the other being *reuse*).